# Typescript inheritance extend properties

Tags: typescript, object, inheritance, properties

Well I have a simple inheritance of two Objects user and participant.

The user is defined as

```
export type userDoc = {
  firstname: string
  lastname: string
  email: string
}

export class User {
  props: userDoc = {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      email: "", 
      {...}
  }
}
```

And the participant (inheriting from user) as

```
type participantDoc = {
    pseudonym: string
    karma: number
    impact: number
    level: number
    experience: number
  }

export class Participant extends User {
    props: participantDoc = {
      pseudonym: "",
      karma: 0,
      impact: 0,
      level: 0,
      experience: 0
    }
}
```

Now what I am hoping to achieve is to extend the attributes of the parent class in the child class. I am working with props because of mongodb and because its safer to assign it this way instead of Object.assign().

The error typescript is throwing:

```
TS2416: Property 'props' in type 'Participant' is not assignable to thesame property in base type 'User'.
  Type 'participantDoc' is missing the following properties from type 'userDoc': firstname, lastname, email, and 6 more.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to extend the types of props just like you did for class.

Change

```
export type participantDoc = {
    pseudonym: string
    karma: number
    impact: number
    level: number
    experience: number
}
```

to

```
export type participantDoc = {
    pseudonym: string
    karma: number
    impact: number
    level: number
    experience: number
} & userDoc
```

Also, if you are willing to declare your types as interfaces, you could do this:

```js
export interface userDoc {
  firstname: string
  lastname: string
  email: string
}

export interface participantDoc extends userDoc {
    pseudonym: string
    karma: number
    impact: number
    level: number
    experience: number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance can work between `User` and `Participant` classes if `User` is generic to specify the type of its `props` field.

Another tip is to rely on constants (the props values when empty) to get the type. It makes the code terser.

```js
const emptyUserProps = {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "", 
};

export type UserProps = typeof emptyUserProps;

export class User<TProps extends UserProps = UserProps> {
    props = emptyUserProps as TProps; // Type assertion `as TProps` is needed here in order to initialise the field using `emptyUserProps` (of type `UserProps`, not `TProps`)
}

// -------

const emptyParticipantProps = {
    pseudonym: "",
    karma: 0,
    impact: 0,
    level: 0,
    experience: 0,
};

export type ParticipantProps = typeof emptyParticipantProps;

export class Participant extends User<UserProps & ParticipantProps> {
    props = {
        ...emptyUserProps,
        ...emptyParticipantProps,
    };
}
```

But if `User` and `Participant` share only some data in `props` field, it's safer to achieve polymorphism using on a base interface rather than class inheritance:

```js
export interface WithProps<TProps> {
    props: TProps;
}

// ----

const emptyUserProps = {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "", 
};

export type UserProps = typeof emptyUserProps;

export class User implements WithProps<UserProps> {
    props = emptyUserProps;
}

// -------

const emptyParticipantProps = {
    pseudonym: "",
    karma: 0,
    impact: 0,
    level: 0,
    experience: 0,
};

export type ParticipantProps = typeof emptyParticipantProps;

export class Participant implements WithProps<UserProps & ParticipantProps> {
    props = {
        ...emptyUserProps,
        ...emptyParticipantProps,
    };
}
```

Another option is to use a single generic class with several static factory methods, one to create a "basic" user, another one for a participant:

```js
const emptyUserProps = {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "", 
};

const emptyParticipantProps = {
    pseudonym: "",
    karma: 0,
    impact: 0,
    level: 0,
    experience: 0,
};

export class User<TProps> {
    // `TProps` inferred to `typeof emptyUserProps`
    static createUser(props = emptyUserProps) {
        return new User(props);
    }

    // `TProps` inferred to `(typeof emptyUserProps) & (typeof emptyParticipantProps)`
    static createParticipant(props = {
        ...emptyUserProps,
        ...emptyParticipantProps,
    }) {
        return new User(props);
    }

    private constructor(public props: TProps) {}
}
```